# Form validation with jquery - return false

Tags: jquery, validation, forms

Can some one tell my why the folowing code doesn't work. It alerts as it should. But it return true afterwards, even if a field is empty.

```
<form id="theform" method="post" action="mailme.php">
<input id="field1" name="a" value="field1" type="text" />
<input id="field2" name="b" value="field2" type="text" />
<input id="field3" name="c" value="field3" type="text" />
<input id="field4" name="d" value="field4" type="text" />

<input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$('#theform').submit(function(){
    $('#theform input[type=text]').each(function(n,element){
        if ($(element).val()=='') {
             alert('The ' + element.id+' must have a value');
             return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
});

</script>
```

Comment: try to delete `return true`, I know that the first return is important but something tells me that this will work.

Comment: Thanks for answering Adam. Tough, this doesn't work in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use jQuery's [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function with a callback function, and then testing the resulting array for its size, returning `true` if it's zero.

```
$('#theform').submit(function(event) {
  var filtered = $('#theform input[type=text]').filter(function(index) {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      alert('The ' + this.id + ' must have a value');

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  });

  return filtered.length == 0;
});
```

Comment: I like this idea; I had never thought of using filter that way before.

Comment: @Hakan: edited to add the example code. Already tested and working :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works fine as well! Tough I cant tell why this is a better method :s

Comment: Turned out to be better :) Thanks! <script>
$('#theform').submit(function(event) {
var filtered = $('#theform input[type=text]').filter(function(index) {
$(this).removeClass('red-border');
if ($(this).val() == '') {
$(this).addClass('red-border');
return true;
}
return false;
});
return filtered.length == 0;
});
</script>

Answer (score 6):

You're returning from the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) callback function, a `return false` breaks that, but doesn't return from the outer function (your `submit` handler), instead you should do something like this:

```
$('#theform').submit(function(){
    var result = true;
    $('#theform input[type=text]').each(function(n,element){
        if ($(element).val()=='') {
             alert('The ' + element.id + ' must have a value');
             return result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
});
```

In this it finds the first empty element , sets the `result` to `false` and returns in one statement, then returns the `result` from the outer function...if there were no empty fields, this would still be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Your two return statements are in different contexts, so your each function returns false, but that is not the same as a return statement for your submit function, which will always return true on the last line.